# How to add a file and its description to the state using dropzone in ReactJs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, file, drag-and-drop, react-dropzone

How can I add to the state of a component one or more files and their description, using a select, using react-dropzone.

I am using Reactjs, dropzone and bootstrap and what I want to achieve is: add one or more files (by dragging them to an area) and then see a list of the added files and a select input for each one (with options for the user to define the "type") save all of this in a state and then send that information to an API.
Something similar to what appears in the image:
[image]

The code that I have so far, returns me a list of the files that are accepted, depending on their extension (pdf, xlsx ...) and the rejected files, but I don't know how to add a select (with options of "type "from file that can be" summary "," report "," test "...) and save it in a state and then send it to an API.

The code I have so far, using [react-dropzone](https://react-dropzone.js.org/), is this:

```js
const baseStyle = {
  flex: 1,
  display: "flex",
  flexDirection: "column",
  alignItems: "center",
  padding: "20px",
  borderWidth: 2,
  borderRadius: 20,
  borderColor: "#26C2E7",
  borderStyle: "dashed",
  backgroundColor: "#fafafa",
  color: "#c4c4c4",
  outline: "none",
  transition: "border .24s ease-in-out"
};

const activeStyle = {
  borderColor: "#f2f"
};

const acceptStyle = {
  borderColor: "#f8f"
};

const rejectStyle = {
  borderColor: "#f2f"
};
function InputFiles(props) {
  const {
    acceptedFiles,
    fileRejections,
    isDragActive,
    isDragAccept,
    isDragReject,
    getRootProps,
    getInputProps
  } = reactDropzone.useDropzone({
    accept: ".xlsx,.docx,.pdf"
  });

  const style = React.useMemo(
    () => ({
      ...baseStyle,
      ...(isDragActive ? activeStyle : {}),
      ...(isDragAccept ? acceptStyle : {}),
      ...(isDragReject ? rejectStyle : {})
    }),
    [isDragActive, isDragReject, isDragAccept]
  );

  const acceptedFileItems = acceptedFiles.map((file) => (
    <li key={file.path}>
      {file.path} - {file.size} bytes
    </li>
  ));

  const fileRejectionItems = fileRejections.map(({ file, errors }) => (
    <li key={file.path}>
      {file.path} - {file.size} bytes
      <ul>
        {errors.map((e) => (
          <li key={e.code}>{e.message}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </li>
  ));

  return (
    <section className="container">
      {/* <div {...getRootProps({ style })}> */}
      <div {...getRootProps({ style })}>
        <input {...getInputProps()} />
        <p>Drag 'n' drop some files here, or click to select files</p>
        <em>(Only *.pdf , *.xlsx , *.docx files will be accepted)</em>
      </div>
      <aside>
        <h4>Accepted files</h4>
        <ul>{acceptedFileItems}</ul>
        <h4>Rejected files</h4>
        <ul>{fileRejectionItems}</ul>
      </aside>
    </section>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<InputFiles />, document.body);

window.onload = function() {
 console.log('onload');
   
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prop-types/15.7.2/prop-types.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dropzone/11.2.0/index.js"></script>
```

The goal would be to get something like this:

[image]

When adding the files and their description, they must be saved in the component's state, with the objective that when clicking on save, a POST request is made to the API and when clicking on cancel, the state information must be deleted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as @Emmanuel mention in his answer, you can store the files in a state, this implementation store the files in a map using the name as the key.

```js
import React, { useMemo, useState } from "react";
import { useDropzone } from "react-dropzone";

const baseStyle = {
  flex: 1,
  display: "flex",
  flexDirection: "column",
  alignItems: "center",
  padding: "20px",
  borderWidth: 2,
  borderRadius: 20,
  borderColor: "#26C2E7",
  borderStyle: "dashed",
  backgroundColor: "#fafafa",
  color: "#c4c4c4",
  outline: "none",
  transition: "border .24s ease-in-out"
};

const activeStyle = {
  borderColor: "#f2f"
};

const acceptStyle = {
  borderColor: "#f8f"
};

const rejectStyle = {
  borderColor: "#f2f"
};
function InputFiles(props) {
  const [files, setFiles] = useState({});
  const {
    fileRejections,
    isDragActive,
    isDragAccept,
    isDragReject,
    getRootProps,
    getInputProps
  } = useDropzone({
    onDrop: (acceptedFiles) => {
      setFiles((prevFiles) =>
        acceptedFiles.reduce(
          (acc, file) => ({
            ...acc,
            [file.name]: {
              file,
              fileType: ""
            }
          }),
          prevFiles
        )
      );
    },
    accept: ".xlsx,.docx,.pdf"
  });
  const style = useMemo(
    () => ({
      ...baseStyle,
      ...(isDragActive ? activeStyle : {}),
      ...(isDragAccept ? acceptStyle : {}),
      ...(isDragReject ? rejectStyle : {})
    }),
    [isDragActive, isDragReject, isDragAccept]
  );
  const acceptedFileItems = Object.keys(files).map((fileName) => {
    const currentFile = files[fileName].file;
    const onSelectChange = (e) => {
      e.persist();
      setFiles((prevFiles) => {
        return {
          ...prevFiles,
          [fileName]: {
            ...prevFiles[fileName],
            fileType: e.target.value
          }
        };
      });
    };

    return (
      <li key={fileName}>
        <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
          <span>
            {currentFile.path} - {currentFile.size} bytes
          </span>
          <select value={currentFile.fileType} onChange={onSelectChange}>
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="summary">summary</option>
            <option value="description">report</option>
            <option value="report">description</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </li>
    );
  });

  const fileRejectionItems = fileRejections.map(({ file, errors }) => (
    <li key={file.path}>
      {file.path} - {file.size} bytes
      <ul>
        {errors.map((e) => (
          <li key={e.code}>{e.message}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </li>
  ));

  return (
    <section className="container">
      {/* <div {...getRootProps({ style })}> */}
      <div {...getRootProps({ style })}>
        <input {...getInputProps()} />
        <p>Drag 'n' drop some files here, or click to select files</p>
        <em>(Only *.pdf , *.xlsx , *.docx files will be accepted)</em>
      </div>
      <aside>
        <h4>Accepted files</h4>
        <ul>{acceptedFileItems}</ul>
        <h4>Rejected files</h4>
        <ul>{fileRejectionItems}</ul>
        <button onClick={() => console.log(files)}>console log files</button>
      </aside>
    </section>
  );
}

export default InputFiles;
```

You can check it out working here https://codesandbox.io/s/react-drop-zone-select-vhc2l

Comment: Thank you very much, it was just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

`useDropZone` uses a callback `onDrop` which can let you get the names of the files like so :

```
 const onDrop = React.useCallback((acceptedFiles) => {
    // Do something with the files
  }, []);
  const { ... } = useDropzone({ onDrop });
```

Once you have the names of your files each time one is dropped, you can store it in a state, display names and selects and update that state accordingly each time a select is clicked.

Note also that the [doc](https://github.com/react-dropzone/react-dropzone#user-content-usage:%7E:text=React%20%3E%3D%2016.8) says it should be at least React 16.8 but it seems you use React 16.6.

Comment: Could you be a little bit more specific, please?

Comment: @diedu did and example for you.